# BigQuery - Rolling the data every day, how to reduce the interruptions to the Data Studio Dashboard in the process

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a BigQuery table. The whole table will be refreshed every day. So what I am doing now, is

- Load the most current data into Cloud Storage.
- Delete the current table
- Create a new table with the same name
- Load the data from Cloud Storage to the new table (with the same name)

The problems are I have data studio dashboard using the same table as the data source. During the above process, the dashboard will be interrupted, such as show empty data or less when it is just deleted but not finishing the new data load back.

What is the simple good practice I should do to avoid the interruptions to data studio dashboard?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure to turn on BI Engine for really fast results. In beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you deleting the table?

You could totally run a load with truncate.

```
$ bq help load

--[no]replace: If true erase existing contents before loading new data.
    (default: 'false')
```

If you are using the API:

> writeDisposition
>
> [Optional] Specifies the action that occurs if the destination table already exists. The following values are supported: WRITE_TRUNCATE: If the table already exists, BigQuery overwrites the table data. [...]

Comment: Thanks! Right now, like Jon suggested below, I run the refresh in the early morning when almost nobody using the dashboard. But still, no interruptions would be better. Truncate and load from cloud storage will still have interruptions, right? But it would be faster than delete and load which I am using now, I will assume. Or as Mikhail suggested, truncate overwrite and truncate from BigQuery will be the least interruptions, right?

My old way is delete and streaming (no cloud storage middle step) new data in. The interruptions were too long.

Comment: It's a 1 step atomic operation if you load with truncate on

Answer (score 1):

Try below

1. Don't delete initial table
2. Load the data from Cloud Storage to the new table (with different name)
3. Copy new table to initial table with overwrite/truncate

Answer (score 1):

This might be a trivial answer, but why can't you add something like a DateTimeAdded column to your table.  Then instead of deleting the current table and recreating it, just add new data from Cloud Storage, with a newer DateTimeAdded value and once that is done, delete everything that is not the current DateTimeAdded?

This way there is no interruption in your dashboard as data will always exist though there might be a period of instability as old and new data are being used for your metrics.

Is there a time period when the dashboard isn't being used?  Do your data refresh at that time.